# test if page is valid before running javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have some javascript that "freezes" the screen when a submit button is pressed. This is to stop double clickers.

I have discovered that there is an issue if a validator control returns false, in that, the screen has "frozen", so the user can't fix the problem with their input data.

I need to be able to tell if the page is valid or not, so that if it is not, i can un-freeze the screen.

How can I do this??

javascript code that freezes the screen... (originally from 4guysfromrolla)

```
function FreezeScreen(msg) {
var outerPane = document.getElementById('FreezePane');
var innerPane = document.getElementById('InnerFreezePane');
if (outerPane) outerPane.className = 'FreezePaneOn';
}
```

code that runs the javascript...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, button_SubmitOrder %>" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="validateHeader" OnClientClick="FreezeScreen();" />
```

Comment: can you post code where you call `FreezeScreen`?

Comment: certainly... updated!

Comment: It depends what you are using for validation. .net validators, jquery validators, your own custom ones?

Comment: .net validators like RequiredFieldValidator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will probably be something like this.

```
function ValidatePage() {
    FreezeScreen();

    if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
        Page_ClientValidate();
    }

    if (Page_IsValid) {
        UnFreezeScreen();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        UnFreezeScreen();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And on the button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, button_SubmitOrder %>" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="validateHeader" OnClientClick="return ValidatePage();" />
```

Comment: @Andew Walters this doesn't work. It forces the validation and clears the freeze screen yes, but when the validation is successful it still clears the freeze screen :(

Comment: I gotcha, you should just be able to lose the call to unfreeze inside if (Page_IsValid) right?

Comment: This does work. But you have to remember to put `return` in front of the `OnClientClick` function that you call (yeah, I missed that!).

Thanks for your help, really appreciated!